# How does this blinking circuit with op-amp work?

Tags: operational-amplifier

Can somebody explain how this circuit works?

[image: schematic]

1. The OP tries to make the same voltage at the input cables.
2. At first, the LED is on. Therefore we have a low voltage (maybe 1V) on the negative input
3. The positive input also get this voltage (1V)

and then?
Why the LED turns off?

EDIT:
This example comes from the German Book: Kosmos eletronic X3000 (page 15).
R1 = 15 kOhm
R2 = 100 kOhm
R3 = 470 Ohm
C1 = 100 µF
U_B = 9V

Comment: Are you sure that circuit works? What's the voltage at the non-inverting input? Looks undefined to me, unless we take into account non-ideal behaviors of the op-amp.

Comment: It *looks* like someone has tried to build a relaxation oscillator - and got it wrong!

Comment: Source of the circuit, please?

Comment: This is from a german electronics workbook, printed 1989 :) Kosmos electronic X3000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - I totally agree with Olin its a messed up circuit - just goes to show you shouldn't believe everything you read. I think the actual circuit should have been - [image]

Answer (score 5):

No, since this circuit is a mess and underterministic.

Note the positive input driven only thru a capacitor to ground.  Unless this is some special opamp that biases the postive input in some known range (there are actually amps that do that, usually meant for audio applications), the voltage on the positive input is totally dependent on the sign of the leakage current and not a function of the signal.

What someone was possibly trying to do but seriously messed up, was to present the immediate attenuated output signal on the + input and a low pass filtered version of the output signal on the - input.  Such a setup can be made to oscillate with predictable parameters, but that's not how this circuit is wired.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there needs to be correction in the circuit. I can find a big flaw in the circuit where the non-inverting terminal is simply connected with capacitor without any path for the capacitor and the output can never toggle continuously.

I guess you need to connect a register in the negative feedback path. Else there should be a resistor in parallel with capacitor.